# MySQL - retrieving a certain count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

So, Basically I have to generate a report on the no of visits on a page.. well assume this is my table data.
(NOTE: Please assume date-time values for all records)
    visitors         dtime
      a  
 
      c
      b
      a
      d
      b
      e         2013-04-31 03:14:29
      s         2013-04-01 03:14:29
      a         2013-04-01 03:14:29
      b         2013-04-01 03:14:29
      b         2013-04-01 03:14:29
      c         2013-04-31 03:14:29
      c         2nd
      b         2nd
      d         3rd
      d         3rd
      a         3rd
      b         4th
      b

So If the user chooses from `1st to 3rd` , I have to print
Date PageLoads Unique Visits  First time Visits Returning Visits

```
1st   4   3   1  2

2nd   3   2   0  2

3rd   3   2   0  2
```

`pageloads for 1st are - s a b b`, `unique visits - s a b`
problem is finding first time visits , which is only `s`, when compares with every visitor before. 
for 2nd the first time visits are 0, as no one is visiting the first time

my query for finding pageloads and unique visits is-

```
select distinct DATE(dtime) as ddate,count(visitors) as ploads, 
count(distinct visitors) as uvisits,
from table1 where  dtime >= '2013-04-1 00:00:01' and dtime <= '2013-04-3 23:59:59'
group by DATE(dtime) order by ddate desc;
```

How do I find the first time visits for each date?

Comment: Is the field with the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. actually a date field?  What are the rows with no dates?

Comment: yeah, it's a proper date time field, and each visitor has a date-time recorded. I wanted results from 1st to the 3rd, so I didnt write the previous ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create a sub query that returns the first time visitors.

```
select visitor,min(dtime) as firstDate from table
group by visitor
```

Now you know the visitor and his first visit date..

```
select distinct DATE(dtime) as ddate,
       count(A.visitors) as ploads, 
       count(distinct visitors) as uvisits,
       count(b.visitors) as FirstTime,
       count(a.visitors)-count(b.visitors) as ReturnVisits
from table A
left join (select visitors,min(dtime) as firstDate from table group by visitors) B 
     on b.visitors=a.visitors and b.firstDate = a.dtime
where  dtime >= '2013-04-1 00:00:01' and dtime <= '2013-04-3 23:59:59'
group by DATE(dtime) 
order by ddate desc;
```

I don't have mySQL installed on this machine, so forgive any syntax errors, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Looks good :) thank you. I've have to integrate it in a bigger piece of code. Hopefully it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

if 's' is for first time visit then

use sum function

```
sum(ifnull((select visitors from yourtable where dtime<'2013-04-1 00:00:01' ),1,0)) as FirstTime


select DATE(dtime) as ddate,
    count(visitors) as ploads, 
    count(distinct visitors) as uvisits,
    sum(ifnull((select visitors from yourtable where dtime<'2013-04-1 00:00:01' ),1,0)) as FirstTime,
    count(distinct visitors)-
    sum(ifnull((select visitors from yourtable where dtime<'2013-04-1 00:00:01' ),1,0)) as ReturningVisits
from yourtable where dtime >= '2013-04-1 00:00:01' 
and dtime <= '2013-04-3 23:59:59' 
group by DATE(dtime) 
order by ddate desc;
```

Comment: I don't think 'S' is a first time visitor, but rather since 's' never occurred prior to the date in question, it is a first time visitor.